# GCP VM - Able to ping google.com domains, but with curl and wget I get timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Some of my VMs on GCP in Central region are unable to run YUM today, further checks CURL was not able to connect to any google.com domains (no issue running ping and dig) so I am sure it is not resolution errors

```
ping packages.cloud.google.com
PING www3.l.google.com (74.125.124.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.124.139 (74.125.124.139): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=0.983 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.124.139 (74.125.124.139): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=0.505 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.124.139 (74.125.124.139): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=0.334 ms
```

WGET/CURL gets timeout

```
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
--2019-09-09 11:09:09--  https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Resolving packages.cloud.google.com (packages.cloud.google.com)... 209.85.147.102, 209.85.147.100, 209.85.147.139, ...
Connecting to packages.cloud.google.com (packages.cloud.google.com)|209.85.147.102|:443...
```

It happens to my two instances so far, any pointer?

Comment: Welp, it has resolved itself, looks like was a connectivity issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check your firewall. As it seems it has ingress ICMP allow but TCP port 80 not allowed. You could check [similar issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/177401/wget-curl-yum-fail-but-ping-works-centos-5).